# Include global variables in header file - c++

Tags: c++, global-variables, header-files

At the moment I am using a rather large piece of code to analyse data.
In this code apart from the analysis itself, I include some functions that will be used in the analysis, some function that are related to objects and some global variables. My code has the following structure

```
#include "header1.h"
#include "header2.h"
...

#define global_variable_1     1
#define global_variable_2     3
...

double function1(){
  <code>
{

double function2(){
  <code>
{

...

main(){
  <code>
}
```

At the moment I want to make my code a bit more elegant, sophisticated and programmable correct. I am thinking of making a header file that will include the headers that I am using and some functions, a second header file with the rest of the functions and a last header file that will contain the global parameters that I use.

So I will have something like

```
#include "headers.h"
#include "functions.h"
#include "variables.h"

main(){
  <code>
}
```

My question is whether it is programably proper to do so and if there is another and perhaps better way to include the global variables.

Comment: `#define global_variable_1 = 1;` -- seriously ? Is this actual code or did you just give us an approximation ?

Comment: Its fine to add these preprocessor lines to a separate .h file and include the file in headers. No compile code should be in the self made header files

Comment: @PaulR It is apparently an example to demonstrate my "problem"!

Comment: @Thanos: please only post *actual code* - it's OK to trim it down for explanatory purposes, but posting code that is not even syntactically correct is just confusing and wastes people's time. Please at least fix the obvious errors.

Comment: @PaulR : Fixed! Cheers!

Comment: `#define global_variable_1 1` doesn't create a global variable

Comment: @Mat Oops...I have been using this syntax to initialise variable that will be used in my programms. Why is it wrong?

Comment: It's not "wrong", it just doesn't create a variable at all. It's a macro, plain text substitution. Read about them and strive to use them as little as possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use variables that are global and you know that they are a constant value such as PI I would refrain from using both local globals and #define macros. This is a matter of preference but over time I've learned that it is better practice and more elegant to declare them as `static const type name;` in the header file and set the value accordingly in the cpp file. I also do not prefer to have a bunch of dangling values or basic methods hanging around so I usually will group similar types of values and methods and contain them in a class declaring them to be static. Here is an example:

**Utility.h**

```
#ifndef UTILITY_H
#define UTILITY_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>    

class Utility {
public:
    static void pressAnyKeyToQuit();

    static std::string& toUpper( std::string& str );
    static std::string& toLower( std::string& str );

private:
    Utility(); // Not Implemented - This class is not an object and can not be declared.
    Utility( const Utility& c ); // Copy Constructor - Not Implemented
    Utility& operator=( const Utility&c ); Assignment Operator - Not Implemented

}; // Utility

#endif // UTILITY_H
```

**Utility.cpp**

```
#include "Utility.h"

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------
// pressAnyKeyToQuit()
void Utility::pressAnyKeyToQuit() {
    std::cout << "Press any key to quit" << std::endl;
    _getch();
} // pressAnyKeyToQuit

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------
// toUpper()
std::string& Utility::toUper( std::string& str ) {
    std::transform( str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), ::toupper );
    return str;
} // toUpper

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------
// toLower()
std::string& Utility::toLower( std::string& str ) {
    std::transform( str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), ::tolower );
    return str;
} // toLower
```

To use these functions here is an example:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Utility.h"

int main() {

    std::string strHello( "Hello World!" );

    std::cout << strHello << std::endl;

    std::cout << Utility::toLower( strHello ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << Utility::toUpper( strHello ) << std::endl;

    Utility::pressAnyKeyToQuit();

    return 0;
} // main
```

With this type of containment it is illegal to do this:

```
int main() {
    Utility util;

    util.pressAnyKeyToQuit();
} // main
```

This will fail because the Utility default constructor is private or inaccessible, however any type of function or variable that is declared as being static can be called through the scope resolution operator. Here is an example of const variables that would be considered globals.

**GeneralMath.h**

```
#ifndef GENERAL_MATH_H
#define GENERAL_MATH_H

class Math {
public:
    static const float PI;
    static const float PI_HAVLES;
    static const float PI_2;
    static const float ZERO;

    inline static bool isZero( float fValue );

    template<typename T>
    inline static void swap( T& value1, T& value2 );

private:
    Math();
    Math( const Math& c ); // Not Implemented
    Math& operator( const Math& c ); // Not Implemented

}; // Math

#include "GeneralMath.inl"

void dummy(); // does nothing used to have a method in the *.cpp file

#endif // GENERAL_MATH_H
```

**GeneralMath.inl**

```
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------
// isZero()
inline bool Math::isZero( float fValue ) {
   if ( (fValue > -ZERO) && (fValue < ZERO) ) {
       return true;
   }
   return false;       
} // isZero


// -------------------------------------------------------------------------
// swap()
template<class T>
inline void Math::swap( T& value1, T& value2 ) {
    T temp;

    temp   = value1;
    value1 = value2;
    value2 = temp;

} // swap
```

**GeneralMath.cpp**

```
#include "GeneralMath.h"

const float Math::PI           = 4.0f * atan(1.0f); // tan(pi/4) = 1
const float Math::PI_HALVES    = 0.5f * Math::PI;
const float Math::PI_2         = 2.0f * Math::PI;
const float Math::ZERO         = static_cast<float>( 1e-7 );

void dummy(){return;}
```

Using it in an example:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Utility.h"
#include "GeneralMath.h"

int main() {

    float value = 3.14957;

    if ( Math::isZero( value - Math::PI ) ) {
        std::cout << "true" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "false" << std::endl;
    }

    Utility::pressAnyKeyToQuit();

    return 0;

} // main
```

I prefer this approach so that when common stand alone methods and constant variables are frequently used in multiple files and have a similar grouping you do not have a bunch of #defines or global's declared everywhere.

Now on the other hand if a specific class object that you are creating depends on a specific constant value that is unique to it then you can have a global in its *.h or *.cpp file but again I would still declare it as a `static const type name;`

The simplicity of this is to include the *.h file where it is needed and use the class name with the scope resolution operator followed by the const variable or static method where it is needed.

You can also do a similar approach without using a class and not declaring them as static by containing them in a namespace, but this could cause problems because other developers might have the same name space and this could create conflicts to resolve names. This is why I prefer the class approach and declaring them as static members.

Remember these classes are not Objects and they can not be constructed and all members have to be static!